# Remove '/' at the end of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this function to remove http://, https:// and www. from my URLs.

```
function cleanUrl2(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/gi,"");
}
```

My problem is that I sometimes get:

```
google.com
```

and sometimes:

```
google.com/something/
```

The '/' at the end causes a lot of problems with my database. I need my function to also remove '/' if it's the last character.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cleanUrl2(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/gi,"").replace(/\/$/, "");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The URL `google.com/something/` is not equivalent with `google.com/something` the webserver (or code behind it) decides which data is being served when requesting these URLs.

And also `www.google.com` is not the same as `google.com`, maybe they even point to different IP addresses on different machines.

So before you make any replacements think about this.

Comment: +1 btw, www.google.com itself point to different machines with different ip addresses

Comment: Actually (right now, for me) `www.google.com` is an alias to `www.l.google.com` which is pointing to the same addresses as `google.com` does.

Comment: ... and www.l.google.com respond on 6 different ip addresses (round robin?). I was just pointing that the ip->domain and domain->ip is not unique

Comment: Yes, it's a round-robin configuration, and yes it's not unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cleanUrl2() {
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?|\/$/gi,"");
}
```

should do the trick (on ff does)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"google.com/something/".replace(/\/$/,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url = url.replace(/\/$/, "");
```

But are you sure you want to be doing this ? Depending on the web server, the URL won't necessarily work if you remove the trailing slash. You'd be better off fixing the problem with your database code that's causing having a trailing slash to be an issue really.